# How to change styling of a SVGCircleElement object?

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

In my scatterplot I'd like to change the styling(opacity/color) of a circle on mouseover and  also for all other circles which, share the same className.

But `groupList[i].style("opacity", .6);` seems not to be the correct way.

```
var mouseOver = function() { 
    var circle = d3.select(this);

    var highlitedGroup = this.className.baseVal;

    var groupList = document.getElementsByClassName(highlitedGroup);

    // The styling for the circle which mouse is over it.     
    circle.transition()
        .duration(800).style("opacity", 1)
        .attr("r", 16).ease("elastic");

    // For the all other circles which have the same className do this styling  
    for (var i=0; i<groupList.length; i++) {
               // List of SVGCircleElement objects  
                groupList[i].style("opacity", .6); //??
        }     
}
```

Comment: Does `circle.transition()
        .duration(800).style("opacity", 1)
        .attr("r", 16).ease("elastic");` work?

Comment: Yes it works. I just can't do any styling for other circles.

Comment: Have you tried `style("opacity", 0.6);`?

Comment: Yes I have tried `style("opacity", 0.6);` and it doesn't do any changes.

Comment: Have you tried `d3.selectAll('classname').style("opacity", .6)` ?

Comment: @StaceyBurns that looks like it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are already putting D3.js to use, I recommend sticking to it throughout your code whenever possible. In this case your function boils down to basically two statement where the first one is manipulating the main circle while second one will take care of all circles having the same class.

```
var mouseOver = function() {

  // The styling for the circle which mouse is over it.     
  d3.select(this).transition()
    .duration(800).style("opacity", 1)
    .attr("r", 16).ease("elastic");

  // For the all other circles which have the same className do this styling  
  d3.selectAll("." + this.className)
    .style("opacity", .6);

}
```

Please note, that this will only work if there is only one class assigned to the main circle. If there is more than one class assigned to this element, `this.className` will contain a space-separated list of class names breaking the selection.

Comment: +1, I have two classes assigned to each circle. So it means there is no way to do a selection in this case? It was for me complicated to find a way to solve it...

Comment: Of course, there are ways to do a selection in that case. It depends on what you are after: are you looking for a selection of all circles having a) both classes, b) either one of them, or c) just a specific one? If you could be more specific on this, I will adapt the answer accordingly.

Comment: Well each circle has two classes like this `circles groupA` in which all circles share the first one `circle`. The second one varies between circles (let's assume I have 3 classes: groupA, groupB and groupC). My case would be then **c) just a specific one** (the second class). But I'm also curious about case **a) both classes**. I'd like to know how to pass both classNames to  `d3.SelectAll()` properly (considering that I have a space in my sting).

Comment: a) `d3.selectAll(this.className.replace(/^|\s/g, "."))` --> `".circle.groupA"`, b) you have to specify the class name because you shouldn't rely on any order. c) `d3.selectAll(this.className.replace(/\s/g, ",.").replace(/^/, "."))` --> `".circle,.groupA"`. These statements will work for any number of classes, be it one, two or more.

Comment: I think this is the best answer! Except the fact, I needed `d3.selectAll(this.className.baseVal.replace(/^|\s/g, "."))
`. Many thanks. :)

Comment: @user3433097 Are you sure about the `baseVal`? The `className` is a String which doesn't have a `baseVal` property. I can't find a single reference or an example using it that way.